# Why are in JavaBeans the setter Public (JSP EL)

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, properties, javabeans, setter

Why is it required that your setters in JavaBeans are public although it is not a usual way to edit the properties of an object from the expressions, because changing the state of an property is the task of the Controller (in case you are using the MVC pattern).

Does someone know this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVC it is recommended to encapsulate the setter (private). This because MVC discribes that your view does NOT change the model but the controller should do this.

You can use ${model.property = 100}, which requires public setter
Allthough in the MVC it is recommended to private the setter